# How do I access Production Datastore from my local development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a existing Website deployed in Google App Engine for Python. Now I have setup the local development server in my System. But I don't know how to get the updated DataBase from live server. There is no Export option in Google's developer console.

And, I don't want to read the data for each request from Production Datastore, I want to set it up locally for once. The google manual says that it stores the local datastore in sqlite file.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your `app.yaml` enables the "remote" built-in, with a stanza such as:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

This `app.yaml` of course must be the one deployed to your `appspot.com` (or whatever) "production" GAE app.

Then, it's a job for `/usr/local/google_appengine/bulkloader.py` or wherever you may have installed the `bulkloader` component. Run it with `-h` to get a list of the many, many options you can pass.

You may need to generate an application-specific password for this use on your google accounts page.  Then, the general use will be something like:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/bulkloader.py --dump --url=http://your_app.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=allkinds.sq3
```

You may not (yet) be able to use this "all kinds" query -- the server only generates the needed statistics for the all-kinds query "periodically", so you may get an error message including info such as:

```
[ERROR   ] Unable to download kind stats for all-kinds download.
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are generated periodically by the appserver
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are not available on dev_appserver.
```

If that's the case, then you can still get things "one kind at a time" by adding the option `--kind=EntityKind` and running the bulkloader repeatedly (with separate sqlite3 result files) for each kind of entity.

Once you've dumped (kind by kind if you have to, all at once if you can) the production datastore, you can use the bulkloader again, this time with `--restore` and addressing your localhost dev_appserver instance, to rebuild the latter's datastore.

It *should* be possible to explicitly list kinds in the `--kind` flag (by separating them with commas and putting them all in parentheses) but unfortunately I think I've found a bug stopping that from working -- I'll try to get it fixed but don't hold your breath.  In any case, this feature is not documented (I just found it by studying the open-source release of `bulkloader.py`) so it may be best not to rely on it!-)

More info about the then-new bulkloader can be found in a blog post by Nick Johnson at http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Using-the-new-bulkloader (though it doesn't cover newer functionalities such as the sqlite3 format of results in the "zero configuration" approach I outlined above).  There's also a demo, with plenty of links, at http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/ (also a bit outdated, alas).

Comment: I just opened the issue about the bug I mention -- it's at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11635 --including the one-line fix to google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py to make multi-kind dumping work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi). This will tunnel your database calls over HTTP to the production database.

Comment: Alex was 10 seconds before me, but put alot more effort into this ;)