# How to export data from GAE Datastore to sqlite or sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a table in my Datastore and i need to convertit in sql statement to put in my Sqlite Android DB. Are there any solutions? I surfed the web, but i couldn't found a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "convertit in sql statement", but you can get a sqlite file with a dump of some entity kind (or more than one with a little code fix:-) using `bulkloader.py` as I showed recently at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218688/how-do-i-access-production-datastore-from-my-local-development-server/28222817#28222817 -- then, use the sqlite file however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try [approcket](https://github.com/k7d/approcket/). It syncs data from GAE Datastore to mysql.