# Upload Local Datastore with Application

Tags: google-app-engine, import, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the Eclipse Plugin for App Engine, and I have my application running fine locally (able to read/write to the local Cloud Datastore).

However when I deployed to App Engine, the server copy does not seem to have any Cloud Datastore information. Do I need to upload this separately, and if so how do I do this?

Comment: that's correct. It would be a nightmare if it deployed your local development data to production automatically.look at "bulkloader" or similar for such tools to load data to production

Comment: I recently, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218688/how-do-i-access-production-datastore-from-my-local-development-server/28222817#28222817 , answered a question "the other way 'round" -- a `--dump` from the production datastore (for `--restore` to the local one).  I believe the answer would work as well if the `--dump` from from the local datastore, followed by a `--restore` to the production one -- check it out!