# How do I access production Datastore from my local development server using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a deployed app using Google App Engine for Java. How can I use the remote Datastore (from production) with a local development server?

My question is very similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218688/4398714), only I'm asking about Java and not Python.

Comment: Whats your use case? you could depoly your app to a different project id, and use datastore admin to clone the datastore from one project to the new one. By the way i'm pretty sure that `bulkloader.py` solution from the question you linked is just a standalone script you can run. it doesn't matter that your project is in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local program can be authonticated by [`service-account`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

[Here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.22.0/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication) is docs about how to use service-account in java program.

Use env variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/my/key.json
```

Or supply the JSON credentials file:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.KeyFactory;

DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
  .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
    new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
Datastore datastore = options.getService();
KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind(KIND);
Key key = keyFactory.newKey(keyName);
Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
```